# Adam Logan vs. Ben Schoenbrun (2023 Canadian Scrabble Classic): where can JUN be placed?

Tags: scrabble, tournament

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKptvysPvnE), the commentators say in this position

> [image: YouTube screenshot: Adam Logan vs. Ben Schoenbrun]

that if Adam Logan plays JUN then Ben Schoenbrun will play SIJO and win.  However, I cannot find where JUN can be legally placed on this board.  I guess I'm missing some obscure word here.

**Question**: Where can JUN be placed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it's in the top right, hooking onto PI to make PIN.

[image]

His opponent would responding with SIJO on the top row over the triple word score.